# How to turn off screen saver for remote desktop sessions in macOS Catalina?

Tags: catalina, remote-desktop, screensaver, apple-silicon

Purchased an M1 Mac Mini. Running it headless. In the OS for my user, I have the screen saver set to "never." However, when I connect via remote desktop, the screen saver comes on after some period of time.

Where is the plist or setting to completely disable the screen saver for remote desktop sessions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the solution. I noticed an energy saver plist with a UID appended to it.

```
 /Library/Preferences/com.apple.PowerManagement.{UID}.plist
```

In addition to the default

```
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.PowerManagement.plist
```

Reading the default plist with my correct system settings gave me

```
{
"AC Power" =     {
    "Automatic Restart On Power Loss" = 1;
    DarkWakeBackgroundTasks = 1;
    "Disk Sleep Timer" = 10;
    "Display Sleep Timer" = 0;
    "System Sleep Timer" = 0;
    "Wake On LAN" = 1;
};
SystemPowerSettings =     {
    "Update DarkWakeBG Setting" = 1;
};
}
```

Reading the plist with the UID gave me

```
{
"AC Power" =     {
    PrioritizeNetworkReachabilityOverSleep = 0;
    "Sleep On Power Button" = 1;
    "Standby Enabled" = 0;
    TCPKeepAlivePref = 1;
    TTYSPreventSleep = 1;
};
}
```

So I added the `"System Sleep Timer" = 0 and "Display Sleep Timer" 0` by the following linesp.

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.PowerManagement.{UID}.plist "AC Power" -dict-add "System Sleep Timer" 0

sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.PowerManagement.{UID}.plist "AC Power" -dict-add "Display Sleep Timer" 0
```

Comment: Note that you need to reboot for the settings to take effect. As for the Hardware UUID in the .plist file name, you can get it with `UUID=$(system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/UUID/ {print $NF}')`